# Understanding the construction of group extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-extensions

**Definition:** Suppose $G$ is a group with normal subgroup $H$ and that $G/H\cong K$ then $G$ is an extension of $H$ by $K$

Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism of $G/H$ onto $K$. Let $X$ be a left transversal of $H$ in $G$. If $g\in G, g=xh$ for some $x\in X,h\in H$

> is this expression unique? Like I try $xh_1=xh_2\implies h_1=h_2$.

Then $$gx\in \text{some coset }yH\implies gx=yh=ym_{g,x}\tag1$$
$(gH)\phi=k\in K$, let $x_k\in X$ be the representative of $gH$. $X=\{x_k:k\in K\}$ and $x_1=1$.

Now, $(x_kx_{k'}H)\phi=kk'$ and using $(1)$, $$x_kx_{k'}=x_{kk'}m_{x_k x_{k'}}=x_{kk'}m_{kk'}\quad[\text{shorthand notation}]$$
Every element $g\in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $x_k h$ where $x_k\in X,h\in H$. Product of two element, $$x_k h\cdot x_{k'} h'=x_{kk'}m_{k,k'}(x^{-1}_{k'}hx_{k'})h'=x_{kk'}m_{k,k'}h^{k'}h'$$

> How they come up with this product?

The group $G$ is made up of two mappings:

- a mapping $m$ from $K\times K$ into $H$
- a mapping $\alpha$ of $K$ into a set of mappings of $H$ into $H$ (the effect of $k\alpha$ is to map $h$ to $h^{k'}$), $$k\alpha:h\rightarrow h^k$$

If enough conditions are added to these maps, one can reverse the procedure. Consider the split extension.

The second part of the question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791075/1167703), which focus on split extension.

---

Lastly, I couldn't catch the whole story, it seems like the construction isn't intuitive enough. And I couldn't get the similarity with the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension),

> A split extension is an extension $1\to K\to G\to H\to 1$ with a homomorphism $s\colon H\to G$ such that going from $H$ to $G$ by $s$ and then back to $H$ by the quotient map of the short exact sequence induces the identity map on $H$ i.e., $\pi \circ s={\mathrm  {id}}_{H}$. In this situation, it is usually said that $s$ splits the above exact sequence.

Comment: Where is this from? Answer to first question: Yes, multiply by $x^{-1}$ from the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question was answered by @BrauerSUzuki, see the comment. Can you see how $x_{k'}x_{k'}^{-1}$ was inserted in $x_{k}h\cdot x_{k'}h'$?

> $$x_{k}h\cdot x_{k'}h'=x_{k}(x_{k'}x_{k'}^{-1})h x_{k'}h'=(x_{k}x_{k'})(x_{k'}^{-1}h x_{k'})h'$$ Can we go from here?