# Understanding the construction of the split extension of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, group-extensions

This is the 2nd part of another question, mainly [general extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791043). <del>Please have a look to understand the notation.</del> A brief description was copied from that thread,

> Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism of $G/H$ onto $K$. Let $X$ be a left transversal of $H$ in $G$. If $g\in G, g=xh$ for some $x\in X,h\in H$ 
> Then $$gx\in \text{some coset }yH\implies gx=yh=ym_{g,x}\tag1$$
> $(gH)\phi=k\in K$, let $x_k\in X$ be the representative of $gH$. $X=\{x_k:k\in K\}$ and $x_1=1$. 
> Now, $(x_kx_{k'}H)\phi=kk'$ and using $(1)$, $$x_kx_{k'}=x_{kk'}m_{x_k x_{k'}}=x_{kk'}m_{kk'}\quad[\text{shorthand notation}]$$

Consider the split extension where $m_{x,x'}=1$ for all $x,x'\in X$ in $(1)\implies xx'=x''$.

> **Question:** Can we always guarantee the existence of $m_{x,x'}=1$?

Then $X<G,H\triangleleft G$ and $G=XH$. $G$ in an extension of $H$ by $X$.
Therefore we may suspect that if we are given,

- a group $H$,
- a group $K$,
- a homomorphism $\alpha$ of $K$ into the automorphism group of $H$

then we can create a splitting extension of $H$ by $K$,

$$
\begin{align}
G=K\times H=&\{(k,h):k\in K,h\in H\}\\
(k,h)(k',h')=&(kk',h(k'\alpha)h')\\
(k,h)^{-1}=&(k^{-1},h^{-1}(k^{-1}\alpha))
\end{align}
$$

> **Question:** How they come up with this multiplication and the inverse?

Lastly, I couldn't catch the whole story, it seems like the construction isn't intuitive enough. And I couldn't get the similarity with the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension),

> A split extension is an extension $1\to K\to G\to H\to 1$ with a homomorphism $s\colon H\to G$ such that going from $H$ to $G$ by $s$ and then back to $H$ by the quotient map of the short exact sequence induces the identity map on $H$ i.e., $\pi \circ s={\mathrm  {id}}_{H}$. In this situation, it is usually said that $s$ splits the above exact sequence.

Comment: It is better to make every question as self-contained as possible. If you are using notation that is non-standard, even if it is in a separate question here, please explain the notation directly in the question. This will it easier for other people to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @MartinBrandenburg My initial plan was asking altogether in a single thread. I will remember that for my further question.

Comment: Do I need to further modify my thread? Let me know that.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question seems to imply that all extensions of $H$ wit $K$ split. Consider $G=C_4$ (cyclic of order $4$) with $H=K=C_2$.
Regarding your second question, split extensions are more or less the same as semidirect products. You give the definition of an external semidirect product. Here is the definition of an internal semidirect product: Let $G$ be a group with $N\unlhd G$ and $H\le G$ such that $N\cap H=1$ and $G=HN$. Then $G$ is called a semidirect product of $N$ and $H$. For $h_1,h_2\in H$ and $x_1,x_2\in N$ we have
$$(h_1x_1)(h_2x_2)=(h_1h_2)(h_2^{-1}x_1h_2x_2)=(h_1h_2)(c_{h_2}(x_1)x_2)$$
where $c_{h_2}$ denotes the inner automorphism induced by conjugation with $h_2$. Now you can see the similarity to your external definition.

Comment: Thanks for your response @BrauerSuzuki Can you say your perspective on how our construction related with Wikipedia definition? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Perhaps you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product, especially the paragraph before the example section.

Comment: I still couldn't see intuitively the equivalence of $\pi\circ i$ isomorphism and the existence of exact short sequence in [that Wikipedia:semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). But thanks again @BrauerSuzuki It will be a great help if you say something on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791043/1167703).